# Find the area below the polar curve $r=16+16\sin(\theta)$ and above line $y=8$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates, area

So, this questioned popped up on a homework in my Calculus II class, and I'm pretty confused. I am familiar with finding the area between two polar curves or two "Cartesian" functions but not a mixture of the two. I've plotted the two functions together so I have a sense of what area I'm trying to find.

[image: I didn't shade it, but the area they are asking for is the area above the red line (y=8) and enclosed by the polar curve]

The general formula for the area of a polar curve is $\int_a^b\frac12(r)^2d\theta$ where $r(\theta)$ is our function, and $a$ and $b$ are values of $\theta$. If I were tasked with finding the area between two polar curves, I would subtract from the area of the "outer" curve the area of the "inner" curve. I also know that for regular functions of x or y, a similar procedure applies.

But how do I use this here? How do I identify the bounds of integration? And once I do, what do I integrate? I've tried several things and none of it seems to work. Any help wrapping my head around this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note your integral should be $d\theta$, not $dr$. At what values of $\theta$ do the two curves intersect? (And, first, what is the equation for $y=8$ in polar coordinates?)

Comment: Oops, just edited the integral. Thank you!  

At first I thought I could just set $16+16\sin\theta=8$, but now I see that doesn't make sense, and that I'd need the polar equation for $y=8$. If $y=r\sin\theta$, then $r=\frac{y}{\sin\theta}$. Substituting $y=8$, we get $r=\frac{8}{\sin \theta}$.

Do I then set this equal to $16+16\sin\theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find where these functions equal: $$r=16(1+\sin(\theta))$$
$$y=8$$
$$r\sin(\theta)=8$$
Substitute into the first equation: $$\frac{8}{\sin(\theta)}=16(1+\sin(\theta))$$
$$\sin^2(\theta)+\sin(\theta)-\frac{1}{2}=0$$

Use quadratic formula: $$\sin(\theta)=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$\theta_{2}=\arcsin(\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}}{2})$$
$$\theta_{1}=-\arcsin(\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}}{2})$$
We can now apply the [Area Between Two Curves Formula](http://www.mathwords.com/a/area_between_curves.htm):

$$\int_{\theta_{1}}^{\theta_{2}}|16(1+\sin(\theta))-\frac{8}{\sin(\theta)}|d\theta=|\int_{\theta_{1}}^{\theta_{2}}16(1+\sin(\theta))-\frac{8}{\sin(\theta)}d\theta|$$
$$|\int_{\theta_{1}}^{\theta_{2}}16d\theta+16\int_{\theta_{1}}^{\theta_{2}}\sin(\theta)d\theta-8\int_{\theta_{1}}^{\theta_{2}}\csc(\theta)d\theta|$$
$$|16(\theta_{2}-\theta_{1})-16\cos(\theta)|_{\theta_{1}}^{\theta_{2}}+8\ln(|\csc(\theta)+\cot(\theta)|)|_{\theta_{1}}^{\theta_{2}}|$$

Now using some trig identities you can evaluate the values for $\theta$ and get your answer.

EDIT:My orignial answer for $\theta_{1}=\arcsin(\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}}{2})$ has a domain error. However it is evident from the graph of this function that the roots are just reflections across the y-axis.

Comment: I should probably know the closed forms for the $\arcsin$ expressions but I'm kinda blanking on them right now.

Comment: Thank you!! Makes sense now. I didn't think to use the quadratic formula for some reason.

Comment: When I try to compute this using a program like Mathematica, it gives me the following answer: $29.5419 + 20.7236i$. How do I retrieve a real number answer from this?

Comment: Are you taking the absolute value inside of the logarithm? You should not have a complex valued result.

Comment: All I did was input the definite integral from $\theta_1$ to $\theta_2$ as you wrote it above, and normally Mathematica would solve it by itself and give me either an exact or (in this case) numerical estimate of the value of that integral, but it gives me a complex number. It also gives me the angles as complex numbers.

Comment: Just edited, one of the values for the $\arcsin$ had a domain error, which would give you complex valued results. However, it is evident from the graph that the roots are just negatives of each other.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! That makes perfect sense. Your help was much appreciated. I get a value of 36.0859, which makes more sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68685/discussion-between-akot717-and-aleden).

Answer (score 2):

First let's study when do they intersect.

$$r = 16 + 16 \sin \theta$$

$$y=8$$

multiply $\sin \theta$ to the first equation.

$$8= 16\sin \theta + 16 \sin^2 \theta$$

$$2 \sin^2 \theta + 2\sin\theta-1 = 0$$
This is a quadratic equation, I will leave this as an exercise, let the smallest positive solution be $\theta_0$, of which from there we can compute the corresponding $r_0$.

The intersection point is $(r_0 \cos \theta_0, r_1 \sin \theta_1)$.

Notice that the region of interest is symmetrical about the $y$-axis, hence we can focus on the region on the right hand side.

If we connect the intersection point to the origin. This line, $y=8$, and the $y$-axis form a triangle, of which the area should be computable, I shall call this $A_\Delta$.

Hence the quantity of interest is

$$2\left(\int_{\theta_0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{26+16\sin \theta} r\,\, dr d\theta - A_\Delta\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the polar curve can be represented parametrically since $(x, y) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$, where we let $r$ be a function of $\theta$.

Let us then scale all the lengths by a factor of $8$, so that $r = 2  + 2 \sin \theta$, $y = 1$, and the new area is thus $8^2 = 64$ times smaller. Then we have $(x(t), y(t)) = ((2 + 2 \sin \theta)\cos \theta, (2 + 2 \sin \theta) \sin \theta)$. Finding the values of $\theta$ such that $y = 1$ (we know from the graph that there are exactly two):

$$2 \sin^2 \theta + 2 \sin \theta - 1 = 0$$
$$\sin \theta = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{2^2 - 4 \cdot 2 \cdot -1}}{4} = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{3}}{2}$$

The given area is just the area swept out between these two values of $\theta$ minus the area of a triangle. The first value of $\theta$ is $\arcsin \left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$, but the other value of $\sin \theta$ does not lie between $-1$ and $1$. Considering the symmetry of the graph across the $y$-axis however, $r$ obtains a maximum at $x = \pi/2$, and so $\theta_2 = \arcsin \left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}}{2}\right) + 2 \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arcsin \left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}}{2} \right)\right) = \pi - \arcsin \left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$.

Thus we obtain the area as:

$$A_1 = \int_{\arcsin \left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}^{\pi - \arcsin \left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)} y(\theta) \ \frac{dx}{d \theta} \ d \theta$$
$$ = \int_{\arcsin \left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}^{\pi - \arcsin \left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)} (2 \sin^2 \theta + 2 \sin \theta)(-2 \sin \theta + 2 \cos(2 \theta)) \  d \theta.$$

$$A_2 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \left(\left(2 + 2\left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}}{2}\right) \right) \left(\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2} \right)\right)$$

and $A_\text{total} = A_1 + A_2$, which we then multiply by $64$ to get the final answer.